# Keep a table column at the earliest related value of a column in another table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I have two related tables. Lets call them `event_types` and `occurrences` with the following columns:

```
event_types
-------------
id VARCHAR(30)
name VARCHAR(50)
first_event Timestamp
```

and

```
occurrences
-------------
id VARCHAR(30)    
event_type_id VARCHAR(30)
timestamp Timestamp
postal_number Integer
city VARCHAR(50)
street VARCHAR(50)
```

I want to add a trigger which updates the `first_event` in case a new `occurrence` comes up with an earlier `timestamp`.

Use case: The reason is that I need to query this `event_type` table frequently with conditions on the `first_event` and sort it by this field to get the ones inside a time frame.

I tried with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_to_minimum_time() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.timestamp < SELECT first_event from event_types where id=NEW.event_type_id THEN
            UPDATE event_types 
            SET first_event = NEW.timestamp
            WHERE id = NEW.event_type_id
        END IF
    END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER after_trigger_time_updater
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON occurrences
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_to_minimum_time();
```

This fails already due to the select statement in the if clause with syntax error. So how can I achieve such an update via trigger?

I am using Postgres > 9.5 and 10.

One further note: Such updates on occurrences won't come very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the syntax error by putting parentheses around the `SELECT` statement.

But you made another mistake: you defined the trigger `ON DELETE`, and there is no `NEW` record in that case. It doesn't make sense to have this trigger `ON DELETE` anyway, does it?

The SQL statement in the trigger could be simpler:

```
UPDATE event_types 
SET first_event = NEW.timestamp
WHERE id = NEW.event_type_id
  AND first_event < NEW.timestamp;
```

That performs the check in the same statement.

Comment: That should have come to my mind as well. Maybe it was just a long day. Thank you. Final solution in edit

Comment: It is better to post your final solution as an answer, that is less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution after Laurenz Albe's help:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maybe_update_event_type_time() RETURNS TRIGGER   AS $maybe_update_event_type_time$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE event_types t
        SET t.first_event = NEW.timestamp
        WHERE t.id = NEW.event_type_id
          AND t.first_event > NEW.timestamp;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$maybe_update_event_type_time$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER after_trigger_anomaly_time_updater
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON occurrences
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE maybe_update_event_type_time();
```